# access SQL count results using multiple sub queries against one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access with a table having over 200k rows of data.  I am looking for counts on a column which is broken down by job descriptions.  For example, I want to return the total count (id) for a location where a person is status = "active" and position like "*cook*" [should equal 20] also another output where I get a count (id) for the same location where a person is status = "active" and position = "Lead Cook" [should equal 5].  So, one is a partial of the total population.

I have a few others to do just like this (# Bakers, # Lead Bakers...).  How can I do this with one grand query/subquery or one query for each grouping.

My attempt is more like this:

```
SELECT
a.location,
Count(a.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) AS [# Cook Total],  --- should equal 20
(SELECT count(b.EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM Table_abc AS b where b.STATUS="Active Assignment" AND b.POSITION Like "*cook*" AND b.EMPLOYEE_ID=a.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS [# Lead Cook],  --- should equal 5
FROM Table_abc AS a
ORDER BY a.location;

Results should be similar to:
Location    Total Cooks    Lead Cooks    Total Bakers    Lead Bakers
1           20             4             15              2
2           45             7             12              2
3           22             2             16              1
4           19             2             17              2
5           5              1             9               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation -- no need for sub queries.

Something like this should work (although I may not understand your desired results completely):

```
select location, 
    count(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) as CookTotal,
    sum(IIf(POSITION Like "*cook*",1,0)) as AllCooks,
    sum(IIf(POSITION = "Lead Cook",1,0)) as LeadCooks
from Table_abc 
where STATUS="Active Assignment"
group by location
```

Comment: Thank you @ sgeddes
This worked great.  I did this same thing early on, but used a case which wasn't working.  Appreciate this.